# How to avoid Hash Match by ordering the underlying view or subquery in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, optimization

Suppose `a` is a table with 800 rows and a primary key on Id and `bView` is a view that queries several tables and ends up with a total of 8000 rows, and I want to do the following type of query without a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT a.*, bView.*
FROM a
JOIN bView ON a.Id = bView.aid
ORDER BY a.OtherColumn
```

Now, this join will do a Hash Match since bView is unordered, which is frustrating because we could easily sort the results of bView and do a merge or loop join instead and save perhaps half the query cost.  Isn't there a way to make SQL Server ORDER the results of bView to enable a wiser join?

(I can change bView if necessary.)

Comment: Have you tried any join hints to see the effects? Have you tried `FROM a JOIN (SELECT [columns] FROM bView ORDER BY [columns]) b` ?

Comment: I tried LOOP and MERGE join hints, but they are worse because one table isn't ordered by the column in the join condition (thus my question).  You can't ORDER BY in a subquery--but good idea, because that is exactly whant I want.

Comment: Does it work to cheat by using TOP(1000000) in the subquery with an ORDER BY?

Comment: The query is allowed, but it still does a Hash Match after the sort and thus has slightly worse performance.  Good try.

Comment: Adding indexes can help, if you can do that. Maybe cross apply if you can't?

Comment: I don't see what index I can add, as bView is a view that cannot be indexed.

Comment: You can index a view, provided it meets certain criteria. There are considerations around that, but it might be the answer you're looking for.

Comment: You can add indexes to the tables the view references specifically to help the view's query definition.

Comment: Suffice it to say the view cannot be made into an indexed view.

Comment: All the tables underneath the view are indexed well, but none of these indexes dictate the order of the view's results.

Comment: There are ways to manipulate plans such as hints, traceflags, the way you write the SQL, use of temp tables, use of indexes, statistics, plan guides and so on, but it's difficult to tell if that's worthwhile from the info you've given.  Consider use SQL Sentry Plan Explorer and create an anonymised session.  An Actual Execution Plan will really help.  Alternately I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f36d3a4f4fb7108830139abe9d29b1c4) in an attempt to repro your issue, but the *whole* script finishes in under a second.  Can you tweak it to be more like your issue?

Comment: Wow, that's going beyond the call of duty.  OK, change bView to have a UNION of results from B and C and it will be closer.